# Velocity addition formula in non-inertial frames

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, velocity

I am a beginner in SR, so the following may seem to be basic. I cannot find any answer in the text books. If there is any, I would appreciate the reference.

The well-known thought experience used to illustrate and calculate the velocity additional formula in comoving frames is, of an observer (inertial frame of reference S) and a train moving with constant velocity with regard to our observer (inertial frame of reference S'), and a train-passenger moving with constant velocity aboard of the train. The velocity addition formula gives us the passenger's velocity in S.

Now if we change the conditions so:

1. The train is moving with constant proper acceleration with regard to the observer, and the passenger is moving with constant velocity aboard the train
2. The train is still moving with constant velocity with regard to the observer, but the passenger is moving with constant proper acceleration aboard the train

Then, what would be the velocity addition formula in these 2 cases? In case 1, the train's frame of reference is non-inertial, and thus we cannot use the usual Lorentz transformation to calculate the velocity addition formula. In case 2,the passenger has constant proper acceleration with regard to the train and the observer, so the frame of reference is again non-inertial, right?

I have searched for an answer here without luck, so if there is already one please point me to it.

Comment: There is no such formula for acceleration, you still use the velocities at the given time

Comment: If the train has constant proper acceleration relative to the platform, it will be torn apart for failing to Lorentz contract like it should of done.